# Resolution Confusion

Tags: ios, compression, resolution, retina-display

Resolution Confusion. I am delivering compressed video, as high a resolution as possible for an iOS app. Are these the final and latest formats?

1920 x 1080-    iPad 3+/
1136 x 640-     iPad 2,mini, iPhone 4,5/
480 x 270-  iPhone, non-retina

Anything else I need to know?

Comment: Where did you pull these numbers out of?  Did you ever think to have a look at pages like this?  http://www.apple.com/ipad/compare/ and this http://www.apple.com/iphone/compare-iphones/

Answer (score 0):

The resolution of the devices so far are: (landscape)

2048 x 1536 iPad 3+

1024 x 768 iPad 2 / 1 / mini

1136 x 640 iPhone 5

960 x 640 iPhone 4S / 4

480 x 320 other iPhones

Comment: Don't for get the iPod touches. 5th gen same as iPhone 5. 4th gen same as iPhone 4/4s. The rest are like the other iPhones.